# How to setup a background job using Parse's Heroku integration?

Tags: heroku, parse-platform

Does anyone know how I can create a background job using Parse’s Heroku integration?

I was able to create webhooks for a cloud function, which I can call using the REST API. But I am trying to run this logic on a regular basis (as in with Parse scheduled jobs) and Parse keeps telling me that ​*Cloud.Cloud.job*​ is undefined.

I am deploying all my code to heroku using parse deploy, which registers web hooks to all cloud functions but fails to do so with the background job.

Any help/orientation on how to do this will be appreciated